# Why do forked processes sometimes appear with brackets [] around their name in ps?

Tags: linux, process, fork

On a Linux system a C process is started on boot, which creates a fork of itself. It is not a kernal process or something. In most cases a `ps -ef` show both processes as expecxted, but **sometimes** it looks like the following:

```
1258 root       0:00 myproc 
1259 root       0:00 [myproc]
```

i.e. one of the processes surrounded by brackets. According to `ps`:

```
If the arguments cannot be located (usually because it has not been set, 
as is the case of system processes and/or kernel threads) the command name 
is printed within square brackets.
```

I do not understand what it means when the 'arguments cannot be located'. The process is started always exactly the same, and the fork is always created in the exact same way. How can it happen, that sometimes 'the arguments cannot be located' and sometimes they can?

In addition, the process is always started *without* any arguments...

Questions I have:

- What do those brackets really mean? Does the process run at all when `/proc/{pid}/cmdline` is empty?
- Why do I get those brackets sometimes and not always?
- How/Where to fix this problem?

Additional information:

- The process is always started without any arguments! Just the name of the command `myproc`.
- The main process seems to run always correct (no brackets around name, executable in `/proc/x/cmdline`).
- The child process *sometimes* has its name in brackets.
- The content of `/proc/child-pid/cmdline` of a correct running child process is `myproc`.
- The content of `/proc/child-pid/cmdline` of an incorrect running child process is empty!
- Again: same code, different child processes!

Comment: That's the arguments passed to the last `execve` system call that the process (or any of its ancestors) made, found in `/proc/the-pid/cmdline` on Linux.

Comment: The file `/proc/the-pid/cmdline` contains only exactly one word: `myproc`. So if this name appears in brackets in `ps -ef` it means that the argument `myproc` cannot be located. Does it mean the executable itself cannot be located? That it is not in `$PATH`?

Comment: No, I expect `/proc/x/cmdline` is empty when you see `[xxx]`, where `xxx` is the process name (not the first argument to the last command that process executed) as found in `/proc/x/stat`. You can get an empty `cmdline` for kernel processes (no exec), for the processes that passed an empty list of arguments to the last process they executed, or for processes that altered their argv[]

Comment: But how can a `fork()` command create correct child processes and incorrect child processes at random? Please see updated question

Comment: The question is not *WHAT* those brackets mean, but *WHY* I get them sometimes, at random...

Comment: The `fork` should copy the arg list from the parent. Sounds like a stack overwrite. You could see that if after the fork, your process writes to areas of memory it's not meant to, like `envp[0][-1]=1;argv[0][0]=0`. The args are at the bottom of the stack, so it's not that difficult to overwrite them by mistake.

Comment: You might want to run the program under valgrind.

Comment: If the process or any of its parents executed a command (like `/path/to/myproc`), then it will most likely have received at least one argument, the argv[0], likely `"myproc"`. It's generally hard to execute a command without any argument (with no argv[0])

Comment: So under what circumstances does the child sometimes receive this argument, sometimes not? Does a child without executable make sense at all?

Comment: The child inherits the arg list upon the `fork`. It's not the `fork` that makes that  disappear, it's probably what your child process does later [intentionaly](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/110595/why-do-forked-processes-sometimes-appear-with-brackets-around-their-name-in-p?noredirect=1#comment170885_110595) or [not](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/110595/why-do-forked-processes-sometimes-appear-with-brackets-around-their-name-in-p?noredirect=1#comment170896_110595) that does. `valgrind` is a good advice indeed.

Comment: If you started it by entering `myproc` at a shell prompt, then it received **one** argument: `myproc`.

Comment: @Stephane: Thanks for the input, I will try to dig deeper. Unfortunately I cannot use valgrind, so I have to debug the code myself ...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`ps -f` normally shows the argument list passed to the last `execve()` system call the process or any of its ancestors did.

When you run a command `xxx arg1 arg2` at a shell prompt, your shell usually forks a process searches for a command by the `xxx` name and executes it as:

```
execve("/path/to/that/xxx", ["xxx", "arg1", "arg2"], @exported_variables)
```

It should be noted that the first argument is `xxx` there.

After execution, the whole memory of the process is wiped, and those arguments (and environment) are found at the bottom of the stack of the process.

You get the first 4096 bytes of those arguments in `/proc/<the-pid>/cmdline` and that's where `ps` gets it from.

Upon a fork or clone, the child inherits the whole memory of its parent including that arg list.

You get the `[xxx]` when `/proc/<the-pid>/cmdline` is empty. In that case, instead of displaying the arg list, `ps` displays the *process name* which it finds in `/proc/<the-pid>/stat` (for executed commands, that's the first 16 bytes of the basename of the executable file passed to the last `execve()`). That can happen for three reasons (that I can think of):

- The process or any of its ancestors never executed anything. That's the case of kernel threads (and can only be the case of kernel threads since all the other processes are descendants of `init` (which is executed)).

  ```
  $ ps -fp2
  UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
  root         2     0  0 Jan13 ?        00:00:00 [kthreadd]
  ```
- The process executed a command with an empty list of arguments. That usually never happens because programs are usually always passed at least one argument, the command name, but you can force it with for instance:

  ```
  int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc) execve("/proc/self/exe",0,0);
    else system("ps -fp $PPID");
  }
  ```

  Once compiled and run:

  ```
  $ test1
  UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
  stephane 31932 29296  0 15:16 pts/5    00:00:00 [exe]
  ```
- The process overwrites its `argv[]` on its stack.

  The arguments are NUL-terminated strings in memory. If you make the last character of the arg list non-null for instance with `envp[0][-1]=1` (the `envp[]` values follow the `argv[]` ones on the stack), then the kernel assumes you've modified it and only returns in `/proc/xxx/cmdline` the first argument up to the first NUL character. So

  ```
  int main(int argc, char* argv[], char *envp[]) {
    envp[0][-1]=1;
    argv[0][0]=0;
    system("ps -fp $PPID");
  }
  ```

  Would also show `[xxx]`.

  Given that the arglist (and environ) are at the bottom of the stack, this kind of scenario can happen if you've got a bug in your code that makes you write on the stack past the end of what it's meant to write, for instance, if using `strcpy` instead of `strncpy`. To debug this kind of issue, `valgrind` is very useful.

Comment: `envp[0][-1]=1;` will crash for accessing possibly uninitialised memory before the beginning of `envp[0]`, as you need a little more work to get the last element in a C array, but it's nice psuedocode

Comment: @cat, as long as you pass at least one argument (and commands are generally passed at least the `argv[0]`) and one environment variable, `envp[0][-1]` (the byte before the first env string) will be initialised. That will be the last byte of the last arg (the closing `'\0'`) as on Linux the environ string are stored after the argv strings at the bottom of the stack. That's the whole point. Try that code for yourself if you want.

Answer (score 2):

There s no problem in it.
When `ps` is not able to determine the full path of the command because args not available:

```
Sometimes the process args will be unavailable; when this happens, ps will instead print
the executable name in brackets.
```

[Extract from man](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?ps)

See also: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/78461/aix-why-does-ps-display-the-process-name-between-square-brackets/109173#109173

Comment: But there is a problem! Each time the child process is in this weird state, it does not seem to work as supposed to! So for me there is a big problem...

Comment: If you're program make use of th process `args` then it seems normal it does not work correctly. but that would be more a development problem than a system issue in my opinion, I never had problem with the bracket

Comment: There are no process `args`! And the problem sometimes happens, sometimes it does not. Why?